# The A-Z book of Science FIction

Tags: story-identification

I read a book called the A-Z book of Science Fiction from the school library ~30 years ago.

Each story was about a subject in alphabetical order. The first story was about aliens (about how humans get stranded on an hi G alien planet, there was a later story Government about a leader that had implants that let him feel the pleasure or pain of the population).

Anyone have the ISBN or other location information for a book that might match this discription?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this is the Asimov book "Science fiction A to Z : a dictionary of the great s.f. themes" The first story is "Alien Worlds, Too Soon to Die".  A description of the ISBN information can be found at:

A  [1](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC0QFjAD&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fcpc1-seac23-2-0-cust35.7-2.cable.virginm.net%2Fshares%2FUSB_Storage%2FMedia%2FBooks%2FNon-Medical%2FChristopher%2520Anvil%2FChristopher%2520Anvil%2520-%2520Interstellar%2520Patrol%25202%2520-%2520The%2520Federation%2520of%2520Humanity.pdf&ei=U6k5VabBGavHsQS7loDgAg&usg=AFQjCNHcFXIQs2QaBhY29aSCtH2SlqRCYw&bvm=bv.91427555,d.cWc): http://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/detail.jsp?Entt=RDM2241485&R=2241485

Publication information:
Boston : Houghton Mifflin, 1982. 
ISBN:
039531285X 
Language:
English

The short story regarding the leader which feels the pain of the population is "Troublemaker" by Christopher Anvil. You can find an online copy of "Troublemaker" in the collection "Interstellar Patrol II" at the following site. A great collection of short stories by Christopher Anvil.

[Interstellar Patrol II online copy](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC0QFjAD&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fcpc1-seac23-2-0-cust35.7-2.cable.virginm.net%2Fshares%2FUSB_Storage%2FMedia%2FBooks%2FNon-Medical%2FChristopher%2520Anvil%2FChristopher%2520Anvil%2520-%2520Interstellar%2520Patrol%25202%2520-%2520The%2520Federation%2520of%2520Humanity.pdf&ei=U6k5VabBGavHsQS7loDgAg&usg=AFQjCNHcFXIQs2QaBhY29aSCtH2SlqRCYw&bvm=bv.91427555,d.cWc)

[Interstellar Patrol II online copy 2](ftp://cpc1-seac23-2-0-cust35.7-2.cable.virginm.net/shares/USB_Storage/Media/Books/Non-Medical/Christopher%20Anvil/Christopher%20Anvil%20-%20Interstellar%20Patrol%202%20-%20The%20Federation%20of%20Humanity.pdf)

====

Comment: Those links go to password protected FTP sites. Please add the username and password or remove the links (there is no point in links that are not usable by the questions readers)

Comment: Thanks! The description of Too Soon to Die is the story that I remember. I used the ISBN to order a used copy from Amazon.

Comment: @Walter. interesting. I was able to get to the site without any password or other issue. Are you sure you don't have some setting in your browser set that is preventing access? If not I can remove if needed.

Comment: I didn't need credentials to get either of the .pdfs.

Comment: @beichst It was the web proxy at work. At home, without a web filter, it doesn't ask me to authenticate to the FTP site. I haven't seen that behavior in the web proxy before.

Comment: @Walter. Glad you were able to confirm on this. I will leave the links in then.